# How to pipe ffmpeg output to ImageMagick's convert tool?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-10, imagemagick

After a lot of searching I have come up with this to pipe a frame from ffmpeg to imagemagick's convert tool.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:02:01 -i ...\pano.mp4 -frames:v 1 -f png - | convert -sharpen 0x1 ...\pano_00_02_01.png
```

I keep getting this error message.

```
[NULL @ 000002e6cd1e00c0] Requested output format 'png' is not a suitable output format
pipe:: Invalid argument
```

I have checked for png support using `ffmpeg -format` and its listed as `png_pipe`.

I'm using ffmpeg version  4.3.1-2020-11-19-full_build
https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

Comment: try `ffmpeg -y -ss 00:02:01 -i ...\pano.mp4 -frames:v 1 -f png - | convert - -sharpen 0x1 ...\pano_00_02_01.png` or `ffmpeg -y -ss 00:02:01 -i ...\pano.mp4 -frames:v 1 -f png - | convert @- -sharpen 0x1 ...\pano_00_02_01.png` Also be sure your ImageMagick policy.xml file has `read|write` permissions for the use of `@`. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read and https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php

Comment: Also see https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

Comment: @fmw42 Still getting this message. `[NULL @ 0000023fdd580540] Requested output format 'png' is not a suitable output format
pipe:: Invalid argument`

Comment: Perhaps it is on the ffmpeg side. Is PNG a valid output from ffmpeg? Is - the way to pipe out of ffmpeg. Check the ffmpeg docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ffmpeg` there is no muxer named `png` (see `ffmpeg -muxers`). To pipe a single image replace `-f png` with `-c:v png -f image2`:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:02:01 -i pano.mp4 -frames:v 1 -c:v png -f image2 - | convert - -sharpen 0x1 pano_00_02_01.png
```

- If you're doing many iterations of this consider changing `-c:v png` to `-c:v pam` as it is faster (no need for compression) and supports most of the same pixel formats.
- I also added the `-` as the piped input in the `convert` command.
- Originally I suggested `-f image2pipe` as it should work with a piped single image and a sequence so it would be more flexible for a more general answer. It worked in Linux but in Windows the OP got error `av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument`. I don't know why (not a Windows user).

Comment: Now I'm getting this message. `av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument` Then at the end it says `Conversion failed!`

Comment: @DonnyV. For your previous comment you probably omitted the `-`. I added the full command in the answer. Try again.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. This is copy and pasted from my cmdline.
`ffmpeg -y -ss 00:02:01 -i D:\Sussex360Videos\Pond_Brook_Rd_VID_20201119_142144\pano.mp4 -frames:v 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe - | convert - -sharpen 0x1 D:\Sussex360Videos\Pond_Brook_Rd_VID_20201119_142144\pano_00_02_01.png`

Comment: @DonnyV. Works for me in Linux with ffmpeg 4.3.1. Guess I'll start the Windows VM...

Comment: I think it is a Windows thing. Because I seen the same thing work online for people on Linux. Unfortunately I need to run it on a Windows Server.

Comment: @DonnyV. Lazyguess: try image2 instead of image2pipe (since you're only piping 1 image).

Comment: That seems to work but doesn't output the final image. I searched my entire drive and couldn't find it.

Comment: That last hiccup was my fault. It worked!!